# ASP.NET MVC: Display user's role

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-roles

In order to show the name of the user, I use the following:

```
@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Now, I'm having troubles when it comes to display the role name of the user as i don't know how to do it.

Comment: Just retrieve the role and put it in your model that is used in your view.

Comment: @CodeNotFound How can I do this? can you help me

Comment: Do you use view model? If not check this question => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc

Comment: Yes, I'm using View Model

Comment: Share the code where you want to display it.

Comment: You should look at @Rob answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using MVC identity for your role stuff.  Add the following property to your viewmodel:

```
public IList<string> RolesforthisUser { get; set; }
```

In your controller action you can call the roles for the user and populate your viewmodel in the following way:

```
viewModel.RolesforthisUser = UserManager.GetRoles(userID);
```

Where userID is your User's ID in the AspNetUsers table.

You can then list out the users roles on the page in the following way:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var role in Model.RolesforthisUser)
    {
        <li>
            @role
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```